# PHP Codeigniter - Join a table if column does not equal NULL

Tags: php, sql, query-builder, codeigniter-3

**Setup:**

Codeigniter 3 running on a variant of PHP 5 server. Using the Query Builder to deal with the db.

**Background:**

Creating a software that has a client profile. Users can add multiple notes to the profile, and link a contact to that note. The profile then displays all the notes and the contact on the corresponding profile, using the `join()` method from Codeigniter 3's Query Builder.

**Issue:**

A note can be added without a client contact, in the case of a generalised note. This sets the default value of `NULL` in the DB which in turn prevents the ***client_model*** from returning the notes, because it cant join the tables.

**Current code:**

```
function get_client_notes($client_id)
{   
    $this->db->join('nh_note_types', 'nh_note_types.type_id = nh_client_notes.client_notes_type');
    $this->db->join('nh_user_profiles', 'nh_user_profiles.user_profile_user_id = nh_client_notes.client_notes_added_by');
    $this->db->join('nh_client_contacts', 'nh_client_contacts.client_contact_id = nh_client_notes.client_notes_client_contact_id');
    $this->db->order_by("client_notes_added_date", "desc");
    $query = $this->db->get_where('nh_client_notes', array('client_notes_client_id' => $client_id));
    return $query;
}
```

Currently if the value for `client_notes_client_contact_id` is `NULL` it will not return any data for that row.

What I am trying to find out is if there is a way to do the following:
IF the `client_notes_client_contact_id` is not null then join the tables, else carry on past.

Or any other way that would join the tables if there is a value and where it is `NULL`, then *don't* join.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking ... JOINs don't happen for NULL values (because null actually means "no value") and that works on a per-row basis, so you should already be getting results for rows that have a non-NULL value.

Comment: My bad, reworded the question and updated code with the full function.

Comment: @TomPearce `join()` is equivalent to the MySQL join, thus it *won't* join on values where it's `NULL` so are you needing this (`nh_client_contacts`) condition to be a `LEFT JOIN` so the rest can still be found? Before returning the `$query` - `log_message()` the `$this->db->last_query()`. Work with the MySQL first, then fix it in builder.

Comment: @MackieeE Thanks for that, worked like a charm! I'll mark it as the answer if you post it! :)

Comment: @TomPearce Glad to hear it worked out in the end! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *current* MySQL query with the above Query builder would 'build' like this:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   nh_client_notes
JOIN nh_note_types ON 
   ( nh_note_types.type_id = nh_client_notes.client_notes_type )
JOIN nh_user_profiles ON 
   ( nh_user_profiles.user_profile_user_id = nh_client_notes.client_notes_added_by )
JOIN nh_client_contacts ON 
   ( nh_client_contacts.client_contact_id 
       = 
     nh_client_notes.client_notes_client_contact_id 
   )
WHERE 
   client_notes_client_id = 479
ORDER BY  
   client_notes_added_date DESC
```

However, this will require all the JOINs to have an matching ID Available. Thus the correct MySQL would be `LEFT JOIN` on `client_notes_client_contact_id` key, which is as you've requested to be *conditional*.

In this instance, adjust your Query builder to have a third parameter on the [`join()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join#CI_DB_query_builder::join) to make this 'left'.

```
<?php
$this->db->join(
  'nh_client_contacts', 
  'nh_client_contacts.client_contact_id = nh_client_notes.client_notes_client_contact_id', 
  'left' 
);
?>
```

In doing so, this'll correct your query to bring back client_notes regardless of `client_notes_client_contact_id`.